# C# - select system fonts from menu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, menu

I have developed a C# application - I want to now add a menu to it and have an option where the user can select which font they want which labels, etc will then be displayed in.  So on my menu bar i added a Font and then the following in its method.  I had read on net that this would work.  However I am getting FontSelector/Fonts does not exist in current context.  Is there a using directive i must add in order to get this too work and does anyone know what it is?

```
    private void SetFontToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontSelector.ItemsSource = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use System.Windows.Forms.FontDialog? Saves you a lot of work ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.aspx

It's a dialog form you can open, that enables the user to set a font family, size, color, etc. example:

```
FontDialog fontDialog1 = new FontDialog();
fontDialog1.Font = textBox1.Font;
fontDialog1.Color = textBox1.ForeColor;

if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel )
{
   textBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font ;
   textBox1.ForeColor = fontDialog1.Color;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean Hinek - could you elaborate further?  Thanks

Comment: @CollyMcK: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.aspx), the same common dialog used in all other Windows applications to pick a font. But it *is* a separate dialog, so it doesn't display anything in a menu or combo box within your application.

Comment: Thanks for that Hinek - if I want to remove items from this Dialog (i.e - the strike through - the size (i do not want user to change the size - how do I go about doing that?  Also if I have a label that is coded to be Times New Romans - if a user selects for example Cosmic Sans how would this label get changed?  Thanks

Comment: you can set fontDialog1.MinSize and fontDialog1.MaxSize to the same value (font size in pt), the dialog will then only allow the font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can display this list in a combo box for example:

```
FontFamily[] fontList = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection().Families;
```

Comment: Hi Anders - I actually dont want to add anything else to my form - I want to bring up this list and the user to select when the Set Font is clicked on the Menu Bar.

Comment: Either you want to show some form of dialog/control to select font, in that case Use the FontDialog. Otherwise you don't want to show something to select font and in that case have the list of font as menu items or items in a combo or whatever. Otherwise I don't understand "I want to bring up this list". Explain "bring up"